# Chartjs 2.7.2, stacked line chart background color of datasets overlaps

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The background color of the datasets from my stacked line chart mix with each other, just like below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
var chart = new Chart($('#chart-area'), {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    },
});
```

And i create dinamic the datasets:

```
chart.data.datasets.push({
     label: LABELS,
     borderColor: COLOR1,
     backgroundColor: COLOR2,
     data: []
});
```

My colors example:

```
   COLOR1 -> "#000c89",
   COLOR2 -> 'rgba(0, 12, 137, 0.4)'
```

Any ideia how to make the colors look like their normal? They get mixed (i think its because of the transparency), i can make them without transparency, but the chart gets ugly.

Comment: You are right, the colors mix because of the transparency. However, standard `rgba` is not supposed to provide more colors than `rgb`; *the only* purpose of the `a` transparency component is to allow mixing of "foreground" and "background" colors. The nice colors you get by using `rgba` are the result of combining that color "foreground" with the background which is typically white. The components of the resulting `rgb` mix can be computed with `rMix = round(r * a + 255 * (1 - a))`, with analogous for the `g` and `b` components. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4235gL0/) for that.

Comment: Sorry for delay, but your point gave me the answer, its cool to know how to create the same transparency color with math wtih regular rgb. Can you post as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the colours mix because of the transparency. I don't think it's possible to avoid that effect, since the only reason there's a transparency channel in `rgba` is to allow that mixing of "foreground" and "background" colours.

Indeed, `rgba` is not supposed to provide more colours than `rgb`.

The nice colours you get by using `rgba` in chart.js backgrounds are the result of combining the `rgb` part of that color as "foreground" with the chart background which is typically white (`rgb(255, 255, 255)`). The components of the resulting rgb mix can be computed with

```js
rMix = Math.round(r * a + 255 * (1 - a))
gMix = Math.round(g * a + 255 * (1 - a))
bMix = Math.round(b * a + 255 * (1 - a))
```

Here's a code snippet doing that calculation

```js
function runColors() {
  const ctxRgba = document.querySelector('#cvs_rgba').getContext('2d'),
    ctxRgb = document.querySelector('#cvs_rgb').getContext('2d'),
    textRgba = document.querySelector('#rgba'),
    textRgb = document.querySelector('#rgb');

  textRgba.innerText = '';
  textRgb.innerText = '';
  ctxRgba.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  ctxRgba.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctxRgb.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  ctxRgb.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  const r = parseInt(document.querySelector('#r').value, 10),
    g = parseInt(document.querySelector('#g').value, 10),
    b = parseInt(document.querySelector('#b').value, 10),
    a = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#a').value);
  if (r < 0 || r > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || a < 0 || a > 1) {
    document.querySelector('#error').innerText = 'Invalid data';
    return;
  }
  document.querySelector('#error').innerText = '';
  const sRGBA = `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a.toFixed(4).replace(/0+$/, '')})`;
  textRgba.innerText = sRGBA;
  const r1 = Math.round(r * a + 255 * (1 - a)),
    b1 = Math.round(b * a + 255 * (1 - a)),
    g1 = Math.round(g * a + 255 * (1 - a));
  const sRGB = `rgb(${r1},${g1},${b1})`;
  textRgb.innerText = sRGB;

  ctxRgba.fillStyle = sRGBA;
  ctxRgba.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

  ctxRgb.fillStyle = sRGB;
  ctxRgb.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
}

runColors();
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>
    <code>rgb</code> result of mixing an <code>rgba</code> color with a white background
  </h3>
  R:<input type="text" size="3" value="0" id="r" onchange="runColors()"> G:
  <input type="text" size="3" value="12" id="g" onchange="runColors()"> B:
  <input type="text" size="3" value="137" id="b" onchange="runColors()"> A:
  <input type="text" size="5" value="0.4" id="a" onchange="runColors()">
  <div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; border:1px solid black">
    <canvas id="cvs_rgba" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"></canvas>
    <br>
    <code id="rgba"></code>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; border:1px solid black">
    <canvas id="cvs_rgb" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"></canvas>
    <br>
    <code id="rgb"></code>
  </div>
```

also as a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzbcxou8/).

---

**Addendum**

Note: I have to add what I know theoretically about the topic of wide gamut colours as it is indirectly relevant to the question asked; however, this is only abstract information as I never used these color spaces, nor do I have a HDR monitor. Please contribute to this (message/new answer/edit/downvote) if you know more.

Insofar wider-than-rgb(24) color spaces are concerned, that is a large topic, but it's worth mentioning the fact that (at the time of posting, end of 2023) there's already good support for it in browsers. One may start with simple but good introductions like [this one](https://webkit.org/blog/12058/wide-gamut-2d-graphics-using-html-canvas/) or read the specs in [css4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#predefined) and the [githb canvas-color-space pages](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/main/Canvas2DColorManagementExplainer.md).

A simple test shows that chart.js doesn't complain if one uses  `backgroundColor: "color(display-p3 0 1 0)"` but passes that color to the canvas functions. This means one can write wide-gamut ready code for chart.js. However, the way the canvas context is created in the code, seems to indicate that there's currently no way for users to set the color space, not even if a `CanvasRenderingContext2d` is passed as the first argument to the `Chart` constructor.